# Ceiling box has 2 black and white wires but fan/ light only has 1 of each

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, light

Installing a new fan/light with 1 red wire 1 white wire and 2 green wires
The box in my ceiling has 2 black wires, 2 white wires, and one bare wire.
(The 2 black wires were capped together, and the 2 white wires were capped together)

[image]

Manual says to connect the red fan wire to the black ceiling wire, the white fan wire to the white ceiling wire, and the green fan wires to the bare ceiling wire.

[image]

I have connected the green wires, but I do not know how to connect the other wires since there seems to be an extra set?

Comment: Are there any other wires in the box?  What was there before?

Comment: No other wires in the box, just the 2 black 2 white and 1 bare wires. Nothing was there before, the box had a plate over it

Comment: Does this fan come with a remote control switch? Can you post pictures of the wires in the box and of the fan?

Comment: Yes, the fan came with a remote control switch. I'm working on uploading some photos

Comment: Heres pictures of the fan and box https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w0jmi5DBCXYW0ZQyjNPay56-8lQSVZzk/view?usp=drivesdk https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TCxUxTs3dpjKfYKWMd2rS9ihVejLeRqu/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  How does lighting in this room work *presently*?  Is there another ceiling light somewhere? Is there a switched receptacle you must plug a floor lamp into?   There *must* be a wall switch; it's the law.

Comment: @harper yes there is a wall switch with two switches on it in the room; they don't do anything so I assumed they were for this ceiling box. We have just been using a lamp plugged into the wall to light the room; turning on the lamp manually- no wall switch

Comment: Did you really go through and check *every* socket of *every* receptacle to see if *one* of them is switched?  I bet you did not, and if you did, it would explain the mystery switch.   If so, it would also explain why the black/white wires were wired "thru".   Note that to test this, you would need to reconnect them as you found them, but you shouldn't have taken them apart in the first place.

Comment: We have lived in this house for about 5 years, and the switch has never done anything. I have gone around every outlet plugging the lamp in and flipping the switch with no luck. Should I put the wire nuts back on the way I found them and try one more time to be sure?

Comment: @Tami since you already did it, no... and in any case, it's not *that* important, it just had a good chance of explaining/resolving a couple of open questions.  Is there another blank plate in the ceiling for potentially fitting a lamp?

Comment: I checked the outlets one more time- they are always on, the switch doesn't do anything right now. The only things on the ceiling of this room are this one box and the smoke detector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fan is designed to be internally self-switched using the wireless remote.  As such, it's looking for 3 wires:

- Equipment safety grounding/earthing, which is always green or bare (even in Thailand)
- Hot (of some kind), a current supply, which can be many colors
- Neutral, which is a current return, which must be white or gray. (white wires are often not neutral).

Grounds are easy because all grounds get connected together in every case, unless you're doing extreme wizard-work in a test lab, audio studio or factory.

When you see two cables entering, and both blacks are already tied together, and both whites are tied together, that circuit is **carrying current onward to some other point-of-use.**  "It's not *yours* to disassemble" is probably the best way of thinking about it.  We have another question today where someone dismantled one of those, and it turns out it also served *his neighbor's* apartment.

However, you can tap it, by adding your own wires to the bundle.  Usually when it's a simple 2-black and 2-white (or 3-3, 3-4 or any nearly equal number) in a bundle, you can count on the whites being actually neutral.  So voilà, we have found where to attach your fan's neutral wire: add it to the bundle.

We don't *quite* know what those black wires are.  They may be always-hot; they may be switched-hot off a mystery switch.  It would help if we knew where the onward wires go, because builders don't install wires unnecessarily.  *Regardless...* these are the only "hot" wires in the box, so they are our only choice for the fan.  The fan's black wire gets added to this bundle.

That's the best we can do.  Expect one of your do-nothing switches to start doing something.  This may not play well with the remote.

Comment: Fan looks beautiful and works perfectly! And my do nothing switch is doing something!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think is going on.

The box in your ceiling is not connected to any switch.  It was used as a splice box. That is, when two wires are connected, the connection must be accessible, (not behind drywall) and in a properly rated box.  The blacks are always hot, and it carries on to another outlet or switch in your home.

If you want your ceiling fan and light to be controlled by the pull chains, then it's simple.  Simple attach the black and white wires in the fan/light to the same coloured bundles.  I recommend using a [pig-tail](http://community.homedepot.com/howto/DiscussionDetail/Lighting-Fixture-Wiring-Questions-PLEASE-Help-9065000000007tm) to do this.

If you want it operated by a switch, you'll need to do some wiring, which can be awkward.  I'd ask another question for that.

The other consideration is weight -- You need to make sure the ceiling box is sufficiently supported.